# How to create whole screen overlay in MacOS with Swift?

Tags: macos, swiftui

There's an app called [Intermission](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/intermission-breaks-for-eyes/id1439431081?mt=12) that creates a whole screen overlay:
[image]

I tried creating a floating panel which utilizes `NSPanel` (adapted from https://cindori.com/developer/floating-panel), but it is unable to expand beyond the toolbar/app bar.

[image: floating panel]
I know I can create a new window in full screen mode and achieve a similar result, however I want to draw this overlay directly on top of the screen without entering full screen mode. How can I achieve this result in the way the Intermission app does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! The trick is to set [NSWindow.Level](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/level) to `.popUpMenu`. This allows it to appear above the menubar and dock.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. Are you able to provide some sample code?