# How to create a full screen overlay cover on macos using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui, appkit

does anyone know how can I make this view cover the full screen without entering full screen mode? Essentially I just need to get this window to cover the top area where the menu bar is.

I have tried this answer from [this SO](https://Yep,%20but%20I%27ve%20seen%20another%20app%20do%20it.%20Check%20this%20SO%20post:%20%20%20%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75204465/how-to-create-whole-screen-overlay-in-macos-with-swift) post, but it does not work for me.

```swift
struct CoverView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var appDelegate: AppDelegate
    
    @AppStorage(SettingsKeys.popUpMenuMessage) var popUpMenuMessage: String = "Time to give me twenty!"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(popUpMenuMessage)
            
            Button(action: closeScreen) {
                Label("Close", systemImage: "arrow.up")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func closeScreen() {
        appDelegate.hideCoverWindow()
    }
}

struct BlurEffectView: NSViewRepresentable {
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSVisualEffectView {
        // called when view is first created
        let view = NSVisualEffectView()

        view.blendingMode = .behindWindow
        view.state = .active
        view.material = .underWindowBackground

        return view
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSVisualEffectView, context: Context) {}
}
```

```swift
@main
struct GiveMeTwentyApp: App {
    // Accessing App Delegate
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {        
        Window("CoverView", id: "CoverViewWindow", content: {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                CoverView()
                    .frame(minWidth: geometry.size.width, minHeight: geometry.size.height)
                    .background(BlurEffectView().ignoresSafeArea())
                    .environmentObject(appDelegate)
            }
            
        }).windowStyle(.hiddenTitleBar) // hiding title bar itself
    }
}
```

```swift
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, ObservableObject {
    var coverWindow: NSWindow?
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        configureCoverWindow()
    }
    
    
    func configureCoverWindow() {
        coverWindow = NSApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.title == "CoverView" })
        coverWindow?.standardWindowButton(.closeButton)?.isHidden = true
        coverWindow?.standardWindowButton(.miniaturizeButton)?.isHidden = true
        coverWindow?.standardWindowButton(.zoomButton)?.isHidden = true
        coverWindow?.level = .popUpMenu
    }
}
```

This is what CoverView currently looks like:

[image]